# execution of programs at different timee in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to run a program in night and another program in day successively and automatically.i am doing an image processing project for density based traffic control system

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched terms like `cron job`, `task scheduler`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As user yvesmancera suggested, you can either use a task scheduler to run the desired program. Another option is to make your program more clever by having a wrapper detect function detect the average illumination over a period of time and call the relevant program.